# Distinguish which button was clicked in custom UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a custom class which inherits from `UIView` inside of which is a `UIImageView` and button. I'm adding them to my storyboard as `UIView` and let's say there are two views. I have a delegate and a function which executes when the button is pressed and it works for both UIViews.

My problem is that I don't know how to tell which one was clicked. I need to pass it to another VC and then display suitable image in the `UIView` which was clicked. I've been thinking of setting ids or something but it does not seem like a very scalable idea.
And I cannot simply add `@IBAction` because the view is `UIView` as a whole.

Inside the ViewController I've added them as @IBOutlets:

```
@IBOutlet weak var view: CustomImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var view2: CustomImageView!
```

EDIT:
I'm pretty close to creating reusable and scalable solution - I'm just assigning the tag to every object and than passing it and retrieving it. Problem I've encountered is that I would like to access properties of a tag. I didn't find any solution on how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution with delegates**
You could add a custom delegate protocol for your custom view

```
protocol CustomViewDelegate {
    func didSelectCustomView(_ view: CustomView)
}

class CustomView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!  

    weak var delegate: CustomViewDelegate?

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        delegate?.didSelectCustomView(self)
    }
}
```

And in your ViewController you have to check from which view to delegate call comes:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var view1: CustomView!
    @IBOutlet weak var view2: CustomView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view1.delegate = self;
        view2.delegate = self;
    }
}

extension ViewController: CustomViewDelegate {
    func didSelectCustomView(_ view: CustomView) {
        if view == view1 {
            // view1 clicked
        } else {
            // view2 clicked
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution with blocks**
Instead of a delegate, you could add an optional block that is executed if the button in the view was clicked:

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myButton: UIButton!

    var clicked: ((CustomView) -> Void)?

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        clicked?(self)
    }
}
```

And in your ViewController, you can add the block to your views:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var view1: CustomView!
    @IBOutlet weak var view2: CustomView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view1.clicked = { view in

        }

        view2.clicked = { view in

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's not bad and probably works but as I said: not a scalable solution. You can see my answer - that's pretty much all code I've added and in your solution there are a lot if else statements. In my opinion it is better to set 5 tags for examples than create massive if else blocks.

Comment: You could also use a dictionary which maps the tags or view references to images. `let image = dict[tag]` But the better way would be create a custom component which contains your view. So that your ViewController would stay lean.

Comment: @codddeer123 You didn't say what you wanted to do, so this answer contains generic code. If you just want to set an image then you don't need the `if` Statements (although I would use a `switch` if there were more than 2 possibilities. ) or multiple blocks.  You can just say `view.imageView.image = xxx`.  Solutions involving tags are best avoided. They can cause errors due to duplicate tags and searching the view hierarchy each time to identify the tagged view is inefficient

Comment: @Paulw11 it's not that simple that I just want to set imageView of a view. I'm clicking the button, than it navigates to the different screen where the logic is involved and based on the result it gets back to the firstVC and delegate executes the code I've put in my answer. `viewWithTag` let me avoid if/else or switch blocks and it's a generic solution. The best way would be to pass my current instance of CustomImageView but I didn't find a way to do that.

Comment: ok, that was simpler than I thought. In my final solution I'm just passing reference and using (self) in my delegate. @Paulw11 thanks for explaining the drawbacks of tags. Despite it's quite similar to messeb answer now my code is even cleaner - no tags, no switch/ if/ else blocks. I'm just passing the current object and accessing its properties in delegate function in MainVC.